# Incrementation fact in python concept

Tags: python

Hey guys i have found something very difficult to understand for me ..

My code is

```
dicts = {'sadasd':'dfsdf','dsfdsf':'sdfsdf'}

 for i in enumerate(dicts):

    dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1

    print dicts[i]
```

When i executed it i didnt get any output.

But i know instead of  `dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1` `i = i+1` would work fine ..

Can you tell me why dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 not possible .Is it because is list is immutable ?

Any help would be appreciated .Thanks..

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should be getting a `KeyError` on your `dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1` line. You sure you get no output at all? It's probably not running the code then

Comment: can we use dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 in any situations .can it be done in python ?

Comment: The poster's followup questions are beginning to sound like trolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- dictionnary are accessed by key, not by index. Try
  `print dicts[0]`, you will get a KeyError exception
- i is not an index anyway but a tuple : `(index, key)`, for instance `(0, 'dsfdsf')`.

What is it you want to achieve with your + 1 ?

The only way to have a working  `dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1` line is if

- i is a key, but then the variable name is misleading
- it makes sens to add an integer to the value stored at key i.

For instance

```
dicts = {'bob': 27, 'Alice': 28}
# i is a key, not an index !
for i in dicts.keys():
    dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1
print dicts
```

output :

```
{'bob': 28, 'Alice': 29}
```

Comment: i dont need to acheive anything ..i just want to know only ..
 
so you mean dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 cant be done in dictionary ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Python 2 you will get a `KeyError`, because the elements of `enumerate(dicts)` are:

```
(0, 'dsfdsf')
(1, 'sadasd')
```

which are tuples. When you try to access to the dictionary `dicts`:

```
dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1
```

in each iteration it will be:

```
dicts[(0, 'dsfdsf')] = dicts[(0, 'dsfdsf')] + 1
dicts[(0, 'sadasd')] = dicts[(0, 'sadasd')] + 1
```

Note that `(0, 'dsfdsf')` is not a key in `dicts`, so you will get a `KeyError`. Remember that the way of accessing to a dictionary is:

```
some_dict[some_key]  # this will give the value
```

Comment: so you mean dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 cant be done in dictionary  ?

Comment: @user3501595 You don't _have_ any lists!

Comment: @user3501595 yes, because you can access a list using indices.

Comment: @Christian it makes me confusing ..you said dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1 is not possible in dictionary because dictionary are aceesed by vales not indexs ..so it cant be assigned like dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1 right ?

Comment: @user3501595 Dictionaries are accessed by keys. You are enumerating a dictionary, which is giving you (index, key) tuples. You are then using those tuples as keys to try to access your dict values. The tuples don't exist, so you'll get a `KeyError` exception. You're also trying to add an integer to a string, which doesn't work and will give you a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: So you mean dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 can be done is i is the key only and not the index ?...right ?

Comment: @user3501595 Python `dict` objects don't _have_ an index.

Comment: @user3501595 what Matthew said is correct, you can do `dicts[i] = dicts[i] + 1` if `i` is a valid key (that exists in the dictionary) and if the operation `dicts[i] + 1` is valid.

Comment: Yes it can, if the tuple `i` exists as a key in the dictionary. And also, if the corresponding value can be added with `1`. For example let's `dicts = {(1, 2):1}`. Then you can do: `dicts[(1, 2)] = dicts[(1, 2)] + 1`. And the resultant dictionary will be `dicts = {(1, 2): 2}`

Comment: so i need to be the key right ?..i can be done only if i is the key ?

Comment: Yes, but if you are not sure if the key exists in the dictionary, you can use the function `dicts.get(key, default)`. I would recommend you to read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to do. But generally:

### you don't enumerate dicts

You can directly iterate them:

```
for i in dicts:
    print i, dicts[i]
```

gives you the key and value of a dict.

You can iterate an array like:

```
array = ['a','b','b']
for key, value in enumerate(array):
    print key,value
    # now array[key] == value
```

### you can't add an int to a string

if you want the append an integer to a string, you have to explicitly convert it like `str(42)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is *completely* possible to increment values in a dictionary, as long as:

- you're using a key to refer to an existing value in the dictionary and,
- the value can be incremented.

Try this:

```
data = {'sadasd':1,'dsfdsf':2}
for k in data:
    data[k] = data[k]+1
print data
```

Comment: So you mean dicts[i] = dicts[i]+1 can be done is i is the key only and not the index ?...right ?